# Where to put the Lhost and port number| python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have an assignment i have no perior knowledge to use argparse. pls help where to put the hostip and port number

**Error:**

```
usage: server.py [-h] -a HOST -p PORT
server.py: error: the following arguments are required: -a/--host, -p/--port
```

**piece of code**

```
import argparse, sys
import signal
from socket import *

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple test')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--host', help='set lhost', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', help='set lport', required=True)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

host = args['host']
port = int(args['port'])
print('\n\n\n')
print('[+] SERVER IP:', host)
print('[+] SERVER HOST:', port)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments are parsed when you start the command:

```
python3 your_program.py -a 'your_host' -p 5000
```

Output:

```
[+] SERVER IP: your_host
[+] SERVER HOST: 5000
```